# Entry textcolor when text comes from data binding

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm working on an android application. I have an entry with text binded to a property of a view model. I'm trying to change the entry's textcolor (textcolor="white"), but it doesn't work. If I change the binding to a static text (text="test") the textcolor does change to the specified color.

```
<Entry Keyboard="Numeric" Text="{Binding Number}" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" TextColor="White"   >
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue as described. Might need some more context. If the binding is not working for some reason, then it might be that you are seeing placeholder text whose color can be changed with the PlaceholderColor property of the Entry (no custom renderer required).

Comment: Umm are you sure your binding is working?

Comment: My bad, I have a behavior setting to make sure the value entered is a positive number only. In case it is not, I'm setting the textcolor to red, otherwise to default color. I thought default is what set in style. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Please provide feedback

Comment: Batuhan, the issue was due to a behavior I set on that entry. I didn't need the code, although the code you provided seems to do the work.

Answer (score 0):

You can define TextChanged attribute on entry,

```
<Entry TextChanged="OnTextChanged" /> // in xaml 

void OnTextChanged (object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) //in cs
{
    Entry entry = sender as Entry;
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(entry.Text))
    {
       entry.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```

> Or directly access your entry via Name attribute.

```
<Entry Name="MyEntry" /> //like this in xaml 

MyEntry.TextChanged += (sender, e) =>  //in cs
{
   var entry = sender as Entry;
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(entry.Text))
   {
      entry.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
   } 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a behavior setting to make sure the value entered is a positive number only. In case it is not, I'm setting the textcolor to red, otherwise to default color. I thought default is what set in the style property.